# C++: clang-format with git

Tags: c++, git, clang-format

The project I normally work on gave me the following error today when I try to commit in a new branch:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/hooks/pre-commit", line 86, in <module>
    clang_format(f)
  File ".git/hooks/pre-commit", line 41, in clang_format
    action = raw_input('{} does not conform to clang-format rules. '
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Any idea how I can fix this? At least just get my codes commit. Thanks!

Comment: This is a Python error. Nothing specific to C++ or git.

Comment: How do I get my code (in the c++ project) commit?

Comment: Well. I suggest you ask yourself if you recently has a Python 2 installation on your system switched out for Python 3. That would explain the Python error.

Comment: I didn't use Python 2 in my system at all ...

Comment: Someone sure did. `raw_input` is Python 2, and renamed to simply `input` in Python 3. Things don't just randomly break like that, someone changed the hook or your system. You need to figure out which it was, we can't do that for you.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the clang-format and just get the code committed?

Comment: The only thing I did is Mac update. Can I manually change raw_input to input in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can temporarily disable the pre-commit hook to secure your changes before trying to understand what's going on on your system.

Either commit with the [`--no-verify`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---no-verify) flag or disable the hook if you need to do multiple commits.

#### By-passing the hook for a commit

```
git commit --no-verify
```

#### By-passing the hook for all the commits to come

At the root of your git project, do:

```
chmod -x .git/hooks/pre-commit
```

This disables the hook calling the vexing python script and let you commit whatever you want without any check. Beware though, *no check is performed*.

Answer (score 1):

As several people mentioned in comments, it's clear that what is happening here is that a Python-2.x script is being interpreted by a Python-3.x interpreter.

Systems with both flavors of Python installed will sometimes use the name `python2` to invoke the Python 2.x interpreter and `python3` to invoke the Python 3.y interpreter.  (The value of `x` and `y` here may vary, though no one should be using anything earlier than Python 2.7 these days, and [it's a good idea to move to Python 3 soon](https://pythonclock.org/).)

Converting a Python 2 script to Python 3 is usually pretty easy, but if you have both interpreters installed, and your script itself simply reads:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
... script ...
```

the quickest way to make it use Python 2, if that's still on your system under the name `python2`, is to change the first line to read:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
```

The first line may vary somewhat but the general idea is that `#!` is followed by the full path name of the interpreter, then any argument for that interpreter.  Using `/usr/bin/env` as the interpreter allows further path-searching, so that you can then have it find `python`, `python2`, `python3`, `python3.6`, `python3.7`, etc., as appropriate.

As [YSC answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416954/1256452), from the Git side, you can just skip the entire pre-commit script.